# Ionic 2 ion-input no browser autofill?

Tags: input, ionic2

I'm working on a login form, with two fields: `email` and `password`, using the ionic2 framework.

```
   <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Email</ion-label>
        <ion-input formControlName="email" type="text" #emailModel></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
        <ion-input formControlName="password" [type]="isActive ? 'text' : 'password'"></ion-input>  </ion-item> 
    <ion-grid padding>
```

After a few tests I've noticed that when I type an email already typed before no autofill pops under the input as it normally does for a normal `input`. Is this normal behaviour for a login form?

Comment: just curious if is something about my computer or browser or if autofill is not working for an `ion-input` field

Comment: Much better, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The fix that I've figured was this:`autocomplete="on"` and `name="email"`

```
 <ion-input autocomplete="on" name="email" formControlName="email" type="text" #emailModel></ion-input>
```